# How to string.find the square bracket character in lua?

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching

So I'm trying to find square brackets inside a string:

```
s = "testing [something] something else"
x,y = string.find(s,"[")
```

which gives me an error: malformed pattern (missing ']').

I also tried:

```
x,y = string.find(s,"\[")
```

giving me the same error.

And this:

```
x,y = string.find(s,"\\[")
```

in this case x and y are nil.

Any thoughts on how to do this properly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

John's answer will work -- turning off pattern matching.

What you're trying to do -- escape the `[` -- is done with the `%` character in Lua:

```
 x,y = string.find(s,'%[')
```

Also strings in Lua all have the string module as their metatable, so you could just say:

```
 x,y = s:find('%[')
```

or even:

```
 x,y = s:find'%['
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the fourth argument to [`string.find`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.find), which turns off pattern-matching.

```
x, y = string.find(s, "[", nil, true)
```

Comment: That works fine, thank you.
But what I'm trying to do now it to find this pattern:
"[..:..]"
which means: a bracket, two '.' meaning any character, the ':', again 2 '.', and another bracket.
Should I split the problem in 2 or more string.find? Thanks.

Comment: Oh Mud anwsered that: just use the '%[' so now i can use '.' as a wildcard character. thanks again

Comment: Right—in that case use Mud's answer. You can escape a character such as `[` with the `%` symbol; so you could use a pattern of `"%[..:..%]"`.