# Finding '.' with string.find()

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I'm trying to make a simple string manipulation: getting the a file's name, without the extension. Only, `string.find()` seem to have an issue with dots:

```
s = 'crate.png'
i, j = string.find(s, '.')
print(i, j) --> 1 1
```

And only with dots:

```
s = 'crate.png'
i, j = string.find(s, 'p')
print(i, j) --> 7 7
```

Is that a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: See [How to string.find the square bracket character in lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077423/how-to-string-find-the-square-bracket-character-in-lua).  Although it refers to a different special character, the solution is the same.

Answer (score 25):

`string.find()`, by default, does not find strings in strings, it finds [patterns](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial) in strings. More complete info can be found at the link, but here is the relevant part;

> The '.' represents a wildcard character, which can represent **any character**.

To actually find the string `.`, the period needs to be escaped with a percent sign, `%.`

EDIT: Alternately, you can pass in some extra arguments, `find(pattern, init, plain)` which allows you to pass in `true` as a last argument and search for plain strings. That would make your statement;

```
> i, j = string.find(s, '.', 1, true)   -- plain search starting at character 1
> print(i, j) 
6 6
```

Comment: -1; The escape character for Lua [patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1) is `%`, not `\ `. Trying to use a backslash will probably give you an "invalid escape sequence" error.

Comment: @missingno You're of course correct, I mixed up the escape character for escape sequences and patterns. Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 10):

Do either `string.find(s, '%.')` or `string.find(s, '.', 1, true)`

Answer (score 5):

The other answers have already explained what's wrong. For completeness, if you're only interested in the file's base name you can use `string.match`. For example:

```
string.match("crate.png", "(%w+)%.")  --> "crate"
```