# why does lua string.find return true for this test case?

Tags: string, lua

I'm just new to lua... and so I apologize if i'm missing something basic.
i'm running a simple test to see if i can find certain values in a string.

Here's the code:

```
print(string.find('fd@testca','.') )
```

Instead of failing, which is what I was expecting, I'm getting back:

```
mymachinename:/usr/share/std/test# lua test.lua
1       1
```

Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258313/finding-with-string-find

Answer (score 6):

This is because in Lua the `find` method looks for a *pattern*, and [`.` represents any character](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial).

You can use character sets to work around the problem:

```
print(string.find('fd@testca','[.]') )
```

Here is a [link to a small demo](http://ideone.com/CgaFph).

Comment: It's easier to use `%` as an escape character, similar to the use of backslash in regular expressions: `print(string.find('fd@testca','%.') )`

Comment: @KeithThompson That's nice to know, thanks! I'm only a casual user of Lua, so my knowledge is rather limited on the details.

Comment: @KeithThompson I personally think that's a matter of taste. When it comes to escaping symbols like parentheses, I find `[(]` and `[)]` much more readable than `%(` and `%)` - especially when it's interleaved with actual grouping parentheses. Using a character class to escape a single character creates a nice little square that is easily recognizable in a longer pattern, and it also doesn't the "center" of a character (in `%(` the actual information is right of the center of what I'm looking at) - I think that really helps with spotting matching parentheses and the like.

Answer (score 3):

Lua uses patterns (described [here](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html)) to search. You can turn off patterns with the optional fourth parameter:

```
print(string.find('fd@testca','.', 1, true) )
```

The optional third parameter (1) is the starting position.

Comment: No, Lua doesn't use regular expressions; it uses *patterns*, [described here](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) (because the implementation uses much less code).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Sorry, I was paraphrasing from the lua-users wiki: "Turn off the regular expression feature by using the optional fourth argument 'plain'." Regardless, the fourth boolean parameter allows for a plain text search.