# Corona string.find() : Finding "."

Tags: string, lua, coronasdk, lua-patterns

I'm trying to split a string into two parts, which is divided by a `'.'` character. But `string.find()` function cant handle that

I have this kind of string

```
local test = "345345.57573"
```

I tried

```
local start = string.find( test, "." )
local start = string.find( test, "\." )
local start = string.find( test, "(%w+).(%w+)" )
```

But none of them worked. String.find() always return `1` which is false.
What might be the problem?

Edit:
I also tried to use `gsub` and change . with another character but it didn't work either

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding '.' with string.find()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258313/finding-with-string-find)

Comment: Ok course if you simply want the two numbers then a = {string.match("2353445.23434","(%w+)%.(%w+)")}
will return a table with the numbers in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example

```
function split(pString, pPattern)

    if string.find(pString,".") then
        pString = string.gsub(pString,"%.","'.'")
    end

    if pPattern == "." then
        pPattern = "'.'"
    end

    local Table = {}  -- NOTE: use {n = 0} in Lua-5.0
    local fpat = "(.-)" .. pPattern
    local last_end = 1
    local s, e, cap = pString:find(fpat, 1)
    while s do
        if s ~= 1 or cap ~= "" then
            table.insert(Table,cap)
        end
        last_end = e+1
        s, e, cap = pString:find(fpat, last_end)
    end
    if last_end <= #pString then
        cap = pString:sub(last_end)
        table.insert(Table, cap)
    end

    return Table
end

local myDataTable = split("345345.57573",".")

--Loop Through and print the last split data table

print(myDataTable[1]) --345345
print(myDataTable[2]) --57573
```

[Reference](http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/simple-string-split-function-method)

Comment: Thanks, it works flawlessly.. It seems that I should have use "%." instead of "."      That works the problem too..

Answer (score 5):

Just use `%.` in a pattern to match.

```
local start = string.find( test, "%." )
```

Unlike many other languages, Lua uses `%` to escape the following magic characters:

```
( ) . % + - * ? [ ] ^ $
```

When in doubt, you can escape any non-alphanumeric character with `%`, Lua is fine with it even if the character isn't one of the magic characters.