# Lua string.find not working with decimal

Tags: string, lua

```
pos = string.find("1.23x", ".")
print ( pos )
```

I always get 1, when the output should be 2. Even if I try this

```
pos = string.find("123x", ".")
print ( pos )
```

It still returns 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Corona string.find() : Finding "."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522384/corona-string-find-finding)

Comment: @YuHao, to be exact - this a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17525129/1150918).
Use `%.` instead, because `.` is reserved and needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Forgot that Lua can use patterns, this works:

```
pos = string.find('1.23x', '.',1 ,true)
print ( pos )
```

The dot was matched as a pattern, the fourth argument sets the mode to plain, so it recognises the dot as a regular character.

Comment: Or you can escape `.` like this: `pos = string.find("1.23x", "%.")`